# How do I get rid of the 'Music Creation' and 'Mail' on my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I've deleted everything GarageBand related and delete all emails from Mail. Why is there still 496.1mb for Music Creation and 6kb for Mail? I want these at 0. Please help. [image: storage info screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) For Mail, check if there's anything in iCloud mailbox and clean as necessary. For Music Creation, first use the "Remove GarageBand Sound Library" button under storage management, then try deleting files from `~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` and `~/Library/Audio/Apple Loops`.

Comment: thanks for this answer. all this i have done already, i started with over 2gb and after doing all the cleaning including the steps you mentioned above i ended with the picture as attached. any other clues?

Comment: okay there was another folder that had to be removed which was ~/Library/Application Support/Logic and now my 'Music Creation' is at 6kb. And my 'Mail' is still at 6kb. Any idea how to get them to 0?

Comment: 6kb is so close to zero on a modern file system it is barely a rounding error. My advice to you, ignore it.

Comment: Seriously. 12Kb is less than 1 ten-millionth of a 128 Gb disk. The smallest file you can write is 4 Kb. It's a rounding error, and unlikely to represent any useful space saving for anything. What is your larger goal? Why are you intent on clearing this data?

Comment: "The smallest file you can write is 4kb"....hm, maybe the .DS_Store files Finder makes (even in empty folders) has something to do with the remaining size.